# Make html table respect height of a container with multiple layers of elements between them

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has a great-great-great-grandparent with a `max-height`. The whole chain of elements has to respect this `max-height` and the table is supposed to scroll when it has too many elements for it. However, I can't get it to work.

Here is a simplified version. It's the closest I could get:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: green;
  max-height: 150px;
}

.v-card {
  max-height: inherit;
}

.v-card-text {
  max-height: inherit;
}

.v-data-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.v-data-table__wrapper {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="v-card">
    <div>
      Some other stuff
    </div>
    <div class="v-card-text">
      <div class="v-data-table">
        <div class="v-data-table__wrapper">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
              <tr><td>foo</td></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the table still gets pushed out of the container by the div above it.

I can't remove any of the intermediate elements - you might recognize the class names I've chosen and see why.

I know I could just limit the height of the table specifically, but in my actual code there is another element next to the `v-card` and their bottom borders are supposed to align, so that wouldn't be an ideal solution. You can see a rough mockup here, with the table in question in green:

[image]

Is there any better, more robust way to make this work?

Comment: well ... technically you have a div (`vcard-text`) which is "told" it has a max height of **y**, but it actually only has **y minus x** where x is the height of the class-less div ("Some other text").

I would just drop most `max-height`s and make vcard-text `overflow: scroll` which should still work, even if the data table has a sticky head or whatever, and it's parent obviously flex.

Comment: @Jakumi Unfortunately that doesn't work. Then the table is shown with its full height and inactive scroll bars

Comment: okay, I assumed, max-height would set a height, which apparently it doesn't. giving the .container a height really works well. don't know your use case though...